# Вывод данных из таблицы базы данных порциями

Tags: mysql

Привет друзья!

Нужна помощь, есть база данных, в ней, например, 300 записей, нужно сделать 3 разных запроса, которые бы вывели:
- 1 запрос: первые 100 записей;
- 2 запрос: следующие 100 записей;
- 3 запрос: последние 100 записей;

Помогите, пожалуйста! Удачного всем дня!

Comment: @lxxnutsxxl

    SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT 0, 100

где `tbl_name` - имя таблицы, 0 - количество пропускаемых записей, 100 - количество выбираемых записей. Т.е. три необходимых запрсоа будут выглядеть так:

    SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT 0, 100
    SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT 100, 100
    SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT 200, 100

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Etki? осмелюсь указать на ключевое слово "например" 300 записей=)

Comment: Просто у меня парсер, а хостинг, походу, ограничения поставил на него и не парсит полностью его!  
Вот и решил на 3 части, пока записей более 200, разделить, будет больше - буду еще делать)

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев:*

Для вывода данных можно воспользоваться запросами вида

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT 0, 100
```

Здесь `tbl_name` - имя таблицы, 0 - количество пропускаемых записей, 100 - количество выбираемых записей. Т.е. три необходимых запроса будут выглядеть так:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT 0, 100
SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT 100, 100
SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT 200, 100
```